# VBA export Images with wrong second column name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

[image: I Need to export each image with the name next to it]

First; I need to export the each image of the A column with the name of the B column, but the problem is that the code will export the B2 name with the A3 images and so on...

So at the end the names will be like :
Image - Reference
A3    - B2
A4    - B3
A5    - B4...

Second; The code will not save the images that are repeated.

Sometimes I have 2 references with a repeated image so it will save the first reference with that  image but not the second.

```
Sub ExportImages_ExtendOffice()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20220308
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrImgName As String
    Dim xImg As Shape
    Dim xObjChar As ChartObject
'Set File Dialog Save
    Dim xFD As FileDialog
    Set xFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFD.Title = "Please select a folder to save the pictures" & " - ExtendOffice"
    If xFD.Show = -1 Then
       xStrPath = xFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xImg In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If xImg.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 Then
        xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(B1, 1).Value
        If xStrImgName <> "" Then
            xImg.Select
            
            Selection.Copy
            Set xObjChar = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, xImg.Width, xImg.Height)
            With xObjChar
                .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
                .Activate
                ActiveChart.Paste
                .Chart.Export xStrPath & xStrImgName & ".png"
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried change the code:

```
xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(B1, 1).Value

Set xObjChar = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, xImg.Width, xImg.Height)
```

With no result, still I'm starting with VBA.

Comment: Do you get an error if you remove _on error resume next_? Maybe use _BottomRightCell_ instead of _TopLeftCell_ (because your images reach into previous row). Please check if _offset_ gets the right range (_B1_ looks strange to me)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line

```
xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(B1, 1).Value
```

There is no variable called `B1` in the code you have shown. The problem you describe indicates that it is visible to your `Sub ExportImages_ExtendOffice()` and given the value of -1 somewhere else in your code.

But there is no need for any variable as you always want to address the cell beside the current image. Therefore `.Offset(0, 1)` does what you want. The documentation says

> expression.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)
>
> Parameters
>
> - Name: RowOffset,
> - Req/Opt: Optional,
> - Data type: Variant,
> - Description: *The number of rows (positive, negative, or 0 (zero)) by which the range is to be offset. Positive values are offset downward, and negative values are offset upward. The default value is 0.*

So, use for example (I prefer to be explicit)

```
xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

in place of the erroneous line.